# Automated Android Cert/CA Pinning Test

Tags: android, ssl, https, certificate, pinning

I'm making an android app that uses root cert pinning with the [moxie0 android pinning library](https://github.com/moxie0/AndroidPinning) (just to teach myself about cert pinning). How would I go about writing automated tests to verify my app is pinning correctly. Specifically, I'd like to make at least 3 test cases: 1. Valid and correctly formed server certificate that my app should be able to connect to. 2. Invalid but correctly formed server certificate that my app should reject connections to. 3. Invalid and incorrectly formed server certificate that my app should reject connections to.

My app uses okHTTPClient, and for consistency I'm trying to use okhttp's mockwebserver for these tests. The part I'm having trouble with is making the mockwebserver present the 3 different types of certificates I'm trying to test. I know I'm supposed use the "useHttps" function (MockWebServer.useHttps()) but I'm not sure how to both generate a fake certificate chain that fits each of those 3 test requirements and add those to the SSLSocketFactory that I pass into the useHttps function.

I'm not really sure where to start, and googling hasn't really helped me, so I don't really have a "things I've tried" I can share. I'd greatly appreciate any help.

tl;dr I'm trying to automate https/certificate pinning tests to make sure my app does cert pinning correctly using okhttp's mockwebserver and I don't know how to generate the proper SSLSocketFactory for my mock server.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: is there any answer you got for this? How can you unit test or automate test of invalid certificate  pinning?